# RODBC connection works in RStudio but not in prompt, stuck with architecture incompatibility issue

Tags: r, oracle, rodbc, rscript

I'm trying to exec a R script with a prompt command but I'm struggling with compatibility issues and I can't find the proper way to achieve this.

I'm on Windows x64, I have a x32 DSN that works perfectly when the R script is executed in x64 RStudio (with R x32 by default).

Then I tried to execute this script with System32\cmd.exe like this
`C:\Users\Me\Documents\R\R-4.1.1\bin\Rscript.exe "C:\Documents\Script.R"`
But I get an error
`[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application`

I'v tried to :

- Use SysWOW64\cmd.exe AND bin\x64\Rscript.exe, same error
- Use System32\cmd.exe AND bin\x64\Rscript.exe, same error
- Use SysWOW64\cmd.exe AND bin\Rscript.exe, same error
- Use System32\cmd.exe AND bin\Rscript.exe, same error --> I thought this one would work

There must be something that I don't get...

EDIT: As r2evans suggested, here is the script i'm trying to run with a promp command. I reduced it to the connecting part, the rest is just basic SQL Query

```
##################################### PACKAGES ################################
#******************************************************************************
# List of needed packages
list.of.packages <- c("RODBC", "dplyr","stringr","lubridate", "readr","openxlsx","readxl","RMySQL","data.table")
# Find not installed
new.packages <- list.of.packages[!(list.of.packages %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])]
# Install packages
if(length(new.packages)) install.packages(new.packages)
# Load packages
lapply(list.of.packages, library, character.only=T)
library("RMySQL")
library(utf8)
rm(list.of.packages,new.packages)


connexion <- odbcConnect (dsn = "MYDSN", uid = "LOGIN", pwd = "PASSWORD")
```

Comment: It would be useful to see how you're trying to connect. What's in the script?

Comment: I edited my post to add the script

Comment: If you're using `RODBC`, why are you loading `RMySQL`? It's a `DBI`-helper package, I do not think `RODBC` uses it at all.

Comment: RMySQL isn't used in this one but we'r copy/pasting the same "packages" header for many of our scripts. I'll try to remove it in this one in case it may help

Comment: Sometimes it may indicate where conflicts might be introduced (such as loading `plyr` and `dplyr`). I asked because I thought you might believe it's doing something for you here.